# ¿Cómo se alfabetizan los dígrafos *ch* y *ll*?

Tags: ortografía, alfabeto

La RAE publicó hace tiempo lo siguiente:

> Al tratarse de combinaciones de dos letras, **las palabras que comienzan por estos dígrafos [*ch* y *ll*] o que los contienen no se alfabetizan aparte, sino en los lugares que les corresponden dentro de la *c* y de la *l*, respectivamente.** La decisión de adoptar el orden alfabético latino universal se tomó en el X Congreso de la Asociación de Academias de la Lengua Española, celebrado en 1994, y viene aplicándose desde entonces en todas las obras académicas. 
>   <sub>— [Principales novedades de la última edición de la *Ortografía de la lengua española* (2010)](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Principales_novedades_de_la_Ortografia_de_la_lengua_espanola.pdf) [PDF]</sub>

No entiendo qué significa la oración en negrita. ¿Podrían explicarme cómo va el orden alfabético con unos ejemplos? ¿Es que *-ch-* se alfabetiza entre *-cg-* y *-ci-* y que *-ll-* se alfabetiza entre *-lk-* y *-lm-*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Efectivamente, tu suposición es correcta.

Con la *alfabetización anterior* en el diccionario venían primero todas las palabras que empiezan con *C* [excepto por *Ch*] y luego, **en sección aparte**,  las que empiezan con **Ch**.
Con la *alfabetización actual* las palabras que empiezan por **Ch** están entre las que empiezan por *Cg* (si es que las hay) y las que empiezan por *Ci*.

Lo mismo se aplica a *ch* en otra posición de la palabra y, de un modo análogo, ocurre con la **ll**.

Ejemplos concretos para ***c** - **ch***:

> - A principio de palabra
>
> > Ordenación según la alfabetización anterior: caña, ceño, cirio, columna, cuño y luego **chocolate**
> > Ordenación según la alfabetización actual: caña, ceño, **chocolate**, cirio, columna, cuño
>
> - En otra parte de la palabra:
>
> > Ordenación según la alfabetización anterior: panceta, pancismo, **pancho**
> > Ordenación según la alfabetización actual: panceta, **pancho**, pancismo

Ejemplos con **ll**:

> - A principio de palabra
>
> > Ordenación según la alfabetización anterior: lívido, liza, loa, loable, otras palabras que empiezan por *lo*, palabras que empiezan por *lu* y luego las palabras que empiezan por **ll**, como **llaga** o **lluvioso**.
> > Ordenación actual: lívido, liza, **llaga**, (otras palabras que empiezan por **ll**), **lluvioso**, loa, loable, otras palabras que empiezan por *lo*, palabras que empiezan por *lu*.
>
> - En otra parte de la palabra:
>
> > Ordenación anterior: calambre, calenda, calibre, calor, calumnia, **calle**
> > Ordenación actual: calambre, calenda, calibre, **calle**, calor, calumnia

Comment: ¡Gracias por los fantásticos ejemplos y por agregar aún más aunque ya te había dado el ✅!